# What is the smallest integer $k$ with the property that satisfy this

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> What is the smallest integer $k$ with the property that $$\binom{449}{k}$$ is divisible by 15?

In my number theory class we learn the  $n$ choose $k$ , $c(n,k) = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$  , now we are learning how to use mod with this formula and the question is, What is the smallest integer $k$ with the property that $c(449 ,k)$   is divisible by $15$ ?

If I am correct when I plug numbers in the formula $$\frac{449!}{k!(449-k)!} = 0 \bmod 15$$ since the number will divide by $15$ that's why I set this equal to zero , but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Note: "divides" and "is divisible by" do not mean the same thing!

Comment: oh i see sorry English is not my first language I thought they mean the same

Comment: What have you learned about computing $\binom nk\mod m$?

Comment: when we did the  problem it was ( p-2 ,k)  mod p , which gave me (-1)^k * (k+1) mod p

Comment: To start naively, I'd expand $\binom{449}k$ for small values of $k$. E.g. $\binom{449}1=\frac{449}1, \binom{449}2=\frac{449\times 448}{1\times2}, \binom{449}3=\frac{449\times448\times447}{1\times2\times3}$. For the whole thing to be divisible by $15$, you need $3\times 5$ to remain in the numerator after cancellation with the denominator.

Comment: @mom Do you know [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem)?

Comment: yes i am trying with this theorem but I just confused how to use the roots, I know if 15=3x5 I can use the primes but I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We check the divisibility by $5$ and by $3$ using Lucas's theorem.

We have $449_{10}=3244_5=121122_3$ (base $5$ and base $3$ expansions of $449$). According to Lucas's theorem, one of the digits in the base $5$ expansion of $k$ must be greater than the corresponding digit in $3244_5.$ No digit can be greater than $4$ in a base $5$ expansion, so the smallest number $k$ in which one of the digits of $k$ is greater than the corresponding digit in $3244_5$ is $300_5=75_{10}$ Luckily, the base $3$ expansion of this number, which is $2210_3$ also has a digit that is greater than the corresponding digit in $121122_3.$ Therefore, the answer to the original problem is $75.$

Answer (score 0):

We have $\dbinom{449}{k}=\dfrac{449\cdot448\cdots(449-k+1)}{k!}$ and we know **all these rational are integers**. We want to have $\dbinom{449}{k}=\dfrac ND=15X$ so in order to have $15=3\cdot5$ in the calculations we need to take packets of five numbers. Beginning with $\dbinom{449}{5}=\dfrac{449\cdots445}{5!}=\dfrac{15N}{15\cdot8}=\dfrac N8$ where $N$ is not multipe of $5$.

The way we have choosen is to have successively $(\dfrac{444}{6}\cdots\dfrac{440}{10}),(\dfrac{439}{11}\cdots\dfrac{435}{15}),(\dfrac{434}{16}\cdots\dfrac{430}{20})$ until we get $(\dfrac{380}{70}\cdots\dfrac{375}{75})$ in which finally we have $\dfrac{375}{75}=\dfrac{15\cdot5^2}{3\cdot5^2}=5$ the first binomial coefficient in which we get $\dfrac ND=15X$ as a simple calculation shows.

Thus the searched $k$ is $75$.

NOTE.-It is the evidence itself that the precedent answer given by Reinhard Meier is better that mine. However no everybody knows the aforementioned Lucas's theorem and it is the reason I put this more elementary answer.